# How do I add ohloh.net widgets to my github projects readme.md file?

Tags: github, widget, markdown

I have seen several git repos that those ohloh.net widgets in them.

After signing up at ohloh.net and adding my project, I can see the widgets are available in either JS (script tag) or a google gadget (wiki:gadget tag).

I was just wondering if anyone knows how I can put that into the README.md of my project on GitHub?

Comment: Such questions should be at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works:

```
[![Project Stats](https://www.openhub.net/p/YOUR_PROJECT/widgets/project_thin_badge.gif)](https://www.openhub.net/p/YOUR_PROJECT)
```

Comment: True! Unfortunately, the other ones (with HTML) doesn't have a gif counterpart, it seems.

Comment: I had problems when referencing the gif directly, checked the thin badge source and used this "image generator" instead, seems to work better

https://www.openhub.net/p/YOUR_PROJECT/widgets/project_thin_badge?format=gif&ref=Thin+badge